# How to get nextVal of sequence that works for H2 as well as MariaDB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, mariadb, h2

I use MariaDB as my production database and a H2-Database for testing purposes.

My Problem:
I have a query to get the next value of a sequence which looks like this:

`Query query = this.entitymanager.createNativeQuery("select nextval(seq_stayId)");`

This works fine on MariaDB but it does not work on the H2-Database. However, if I change the query to the following:

`Query query = this.entitymanager.createNativeQuery("select nextval('seq_stayId')");`

it works on the H2-Database but not on MariaDB. I know that MariaDB does not like these String literals but how can I find a solution, that works on both databases?

I would be very glad if you could help me out.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select next value for seq_stayId` is supported by both H2 and MariaDB.

`NEXT VALUE FOR sequenceName` is a part of the SQL Standard, you really should use it instead of various vendor-specific expressions, especially when you need to execute the same SQL in different database systems.

Answer (score 1):

you can create multiple profile properties in spring boot and manage values in properties file

1: application-mariadb.properties

```
next.value.native.query=select nextval(seq_stayId)
```

2: application-h2db.properties

```
next.value.native.query=select nextval('seq_stayId')
```

then you can bind this property using @Value annotation in your required class

```
@Component
    class YouClassName{
        @Value("next.value.native.query")
        private String nextValueQuery;

        public void whatEverIsYourMethodName() {
            Query query = this.entitymanager.createNativeQuery(nextValueQuery);
        }

    }
```

Then you can active your DB profile based on your required env. Also if you have DB specific to existing dev/prod/test or any other env then you can use that property directly in existing env properties files